# UIAlertController foreground is dimmed when it should not be

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a strange issue which is affecting all of many UIAlertControllers shown throughout my app - the AlertControllers' white foreground appears dimmed, or less bright, than it should be.

The easiest way to describe it is to illustrate the desired and expected effect I obtain by placing the relevant code in a fresh 'Test' Single View application (Swift 3 - I should note that the actual app is a Single View application using Swift 2.3).

In my 'Test' app, the code below uses a deprecated AlertView to show a sample message, then builds a AlertController and shows that immediately 'after'.  There is no need to use the AlertView except to highlight the contrast in foreground 'white' - the problematic behaviour is the same if I comment out the AlertView.

Problematic behaviour:
[image: 4 images comparing alertcontroller in Test app vs real app]

Image 1: Test app: the AlertView is shown and the AlertController then shows behind it. Note the whiteness/brightness of the AlertView foreground.

Image 2: Test app: when the AlertView is dismissed, the AlertController is then the uppermost viewcontroller and as expected and desired, its foreground brightness is exactly the same as the AlertView's previously was

Image 3: real app: same code, also positioned in viewDidAppear - the AlertView is shown with the expected whiteness/brightness

Image 4: real app: when the AlertView is dismissed, the AlertController is then uppermost, but its foreground is nowhere near as bright / white as the AlertView's was, OR as it was in the Test app example, image 2.

As previously stated, the behaviour is the same even if I eliminate the AlertView step (which is just for contrast).

One further observation - often when I observe the behaviour, just momentarily when an affected AlertController first appears, as in for maybe 1/4 or 1/8 of a second, its foreground is the correct whiteness/brightness, but then an instant later it becomes dimmed, per the stated problem.

One other observation - some AlertControllers in the real app display properly with the correct level of brightness, but many others do not.

One last observation - I have user the 'View UI Hierarchy' in Xcode and there does not appear to be anything 'on top of' the affected AlertController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    UIAlertView(title: "My AlertView Title", message: "My AlertView Message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()

    let alertTitle = "My AlertController Title"
    let msg = "\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\rMy AlertController Msg"

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Don't show this again", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Dismiss button pressed")

    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        print("I'm action1!!")
    }

    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    let OK2Action = UIAlertAction(title: "Action2", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        print("I'm action2")
    }

    alertController.addAction(OK2Action)

    present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Any help as to this puzzle gratefully received, thanks!

EDIT:

thanks to @Richard G for putting me on the right track - I still have the problem but with more clarity.

So, it you look at the two screenshots below side by side, they are both from the real app, both use the code shown above to generate the UIAlertController (I have now delete the UIAlertView line as it isn't needed), the only difference between the one on the left and one on the right is the one on the right has these 3 lines of code added:

```
let backView = alertController.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last 
backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 
backView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[side by side UIAlertControllers 1 transparent 1 not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IiI.jpg)

According to Apple, "The UIAlert​Controller class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."  OK, so this is hacking into it, and it proves that somehow the alertController has acquired, prior to displaying it, a backgroundColor which was partly transparent.

By setting the backgroundColor to UIColor.whiteColor() the problem is fixed, but the solution should be unnecessary - how on earth did the problem arise in the first place?

How was the backgroundColor somehow set to have a transparency when Apple doesn't even expose that property to me to be able to set?

any answers gratefully received!

Comment: you are wrong, brightness is the same you just have white background, show us REAL test with the same conditions

Answer (score 1):

After seeing an image that you have uploaded I can mention some point.

- The `UIAlertController` is little bit transparent if you notice.
- Since `UIAlertController` is transparent so the background will affect on appearance of alert controller.

NOTE: In case 1 & 2 background is white and case 3 & 4 background is black.

So what you can do it make background as bright as in case 1 and case 2 (from image).

**EDIT : **

TO change background color of `UIAlertController` you can do like...

```
let subView = alertController.view.subviews.first!;
var alertContentView = subView.subviews.first!;
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray;
alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Comment: thanks, when I first read your reply I couldn't detect any transparency in the UIAlertController, however I have subsequently conducted a test by putting a bright red button on the main viewController behind it, and sure enough you are correct, there is indeed some transparency in the UIAlertController! Now all I have do is to find out why and fix it..

Comment: so, am having a lot of difficulty trying to work out why the UIAlertController is being presented with some transparency in my app when it isn't in my Test app:(1) first I thought it might be inheriting transparency from some other view in the ViewController so changed them all to alpha 1, I also eliminated any colour setting with alpha component in the code

Comment: (2) I have confirmed in the meantime however that I AM able to override the transparency problem with some code: `let backView = yourAlertController.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last`
`backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 backView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Comment: thank you again, I in fact found similar code elsewhere and this does fix the issue, as yours does, however I have a large amount of UIAlertControllers in my app, so from my perspective it is a bit of a hacky/cumbersome solution - I would love to understand why the transparency is being set in the first place so as to avoid that happening...

Comment: so the code above 100% confirms the issue arises from transparency in the UIAlertController  I then examined the image view hierarchy in the Xcode interface, I noticed the following things:  - I got a debug message saying "<UIVisualEffectView 0x1360bc280> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1."

Comment: there is also a _UIDimmingKnockoutBackdropView in the view hierarchy, but I couldn't find any reference on the internet as to what this is, but by inference it may be dimming the UIAlertController. Likewise I found a ‘UIAlertControllerShadowedScrollView’ but again can’t find reference as to what it is and how I control it.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView and UIAlertController has same background color and alpha value.
But in your case AlertView is displayed above AlertController, ie why it feels like UIAlertView is Whitier than UIAlertController.

Comment: hi thanks but that is not the case, in images 1,2, and 3 the AlertView, AlertController, and AlertView, respectively are white, as expected - in images 1 and 3 the AlertController is behind the AlertView and is therefore dimmed, as expected. What is not expect, in other words what the problem is, is the AlertController in image 4, which should be as white as the AlertView, AlertController, and AlertView, respectively in images 1,2 and 3, but it is not.. it should be identical to the whiteness of the AlertController in image 2, but it is not... that is the problem.

Comment: please see answer above, it turns out that the alpha of the UIAlertController is indeed ending up at less than 1 - the Apple documentation is silent on how this might come about, but that's what I need to find out. In my subsequent testing, I am continuing to observe that momentarily one the UIAlertController first appears it is completely white background, i.e. alpha at 1, but then a fraction of a second later, it has become a little transparent, and therein lies the problem, thanks